# Iniciando com Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fiz um pequeno fonte com *controller* em AngularJS e ao executar recebo o erro da mensagem em anexo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei onde pode estar o erro considerando que este código é muito simples.

Fonte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Controllers</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="CtrlApp">
        <h1>{{nome}}</h1>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CtrlApp = function(){

    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ronaldo, por favor, poste o texto do erro e não uma imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Tem várias coisas erradas aí.

Primeiro é necessário criar um módulo, depois é preciso registrar o *controller* neste módulo e, para poder fazer com que o **`{{nome}}`** da *view* apresente algo é necessário fazer o *bind* de `nome` em **`$scope`**.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('CtrlApp', function($scope) {
  $scope.nome = 'LINQ';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CtrlApp">
  <h1>Meu nome é {{nome}}</h1>
</div>
```